# Selector function is not calling in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

In first controller, Inside send action button adding notification post method

```
 let notificationhide = Notification.Name("hideLiveBtn")

 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationhide, object: nil)
```

And second camera controller calling notification add observer method inside view didload

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.hideliveBtn(notification:)), name: notificationhide, object: nil)
```

Selector function :

```
@objc func hideliveBtn(notification : NSNotification){

    btnLiveSettings.isHidden = true

}
```

When keeping break points for add observer it observers but it does not calling hideliveBtn function.

Comment: If you send notification before adding observer in second VC, it will not be called. Are you sure before posting notification second VC is added as observer ?

Comment: replace NSNotification by `Notification` in your `hideliveBtn` func

Comment: @SharadChauhan yes camera controller is added as observer

Comment: @CZ54 yes already done that. it does not work

Comment: where you added that `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationhide, object: nil)` show the code

Comment: your code is fine and correct

Comment: @Anbu.karthik then why its not calling

Comment: where you called this NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationhide, object: nil)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169935/discussion-between-pvdev-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @PvDev basically you implement ? NotificationCenter and call NSNotificationCentre

Answer (score 1):

Please implement NSNotification center by some another way.

**Step 1:**

```
extension NSNotification.Name {
    public static let hideLiveBtnNotificationKey = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "hideLiveBtn")
}
```

**Step 2**

In viewdidLoad() of a controller

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationReceived), name: .hideLiveBtnNotificationKey, object: nil)
```

**Step 3**

Selector function

```
@objc func hideliveBtn(notification : NSNotification){

    btnLiveSettings.isHidden = true

}
```

**Step 4**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver("hideLiveBtnNotificationKey")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and its prefectly working.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let notificationhide = Notification.Name("hideLiveBtn")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.hideliveBtn(notification:)), name: notificationhide, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationhide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func hideliveBtn(notification : NSNotification){
        print("notification fired")
    }
}
```